# Mysql comma seperated to json-array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, string

I have some fields in the database that are comma selerated, something like: `a,b,c,d,e`

and I want to convert them into:

```
["a","b","c","d","e"]
```

I know how to do it in nodejs / any other language, but I need to do it directly on the mysql
Possible?
Thanks

Comment: You fell victim to one of the [classic blunders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWW6aDpUvbQ) - the most famous of which is "never get involved in a land war in Asia" - but only slightly less well-known is this: "Never put csv values in a table column!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach probably is to use string functions only:

```
select concat('["', replace(col, ',', '","'), '"]') js from mytable
```

Basically this turns a string `'a,b,c,d,e'` to `'["a","b","c","d","e"]'` - which MySQL will happily understand as JSON, if you use JSON functions on it.

Note that this only works as long as your CSV elements do not contain embedded double quotes.

Comment: *this only works as long as your CSV elements do not contain embedded double quotes* In such case nested replace will help.